# .NET equivalent of Java KeyFactory.getInstance "RSA"/"RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding"

Tags: java, c#, .net

I have the following code,

```
public static String encrypt(String plainText, String key){
    try{
        PublicKey publicKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(Base64.decode(key, Base64.DEFAULT)));
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
        return Base64.encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes("UTF-8")),Base64.DEFAULT);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I want to convert this to C#. I have tried CryptUtils but it doesn't work https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Common/CryptUtils.cs

Sample key,

```
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ9AMIIBCgKCAQEAoqB1N9kugk4UKYnbh0fcg3qYyYKP0m4B
MjWd05ReeAdj+7JRYDEKO6xthDdVSdRO1/2V+YtY8DnXWnxRaICwu8235s3imZCyqgYnomPWdY+F
K540oTz/zug+9wbrlzt/WQFUU4lPlQbzm/Gjw8XfaCozT0e3bnWQcD7rORCOyuJgwSGgREjTv1ss
pgEaKTMknii9vpGZLeAXwoeIYROhuT4IoIkPDhtY0/UZiCi6v7Ja2dmy53VlWIkcm3rcnSJdvpXr
OgiHvaNABHmeymNycNqd6WUaysBRheluQ86nq/2nZPW0gcvmYt5zbMMYX3yY/n2WtAKeNQBAEW1q
b0s6MwIDAQAB
```

Possible encryped value,

```
Y3VTjghDnTrCeG8C/RklKsJ3Y0Mt89sSGGin28E4iQPQvKqeZBws7rBQEZaRamDWftxCkEYZs4Qh
V2l4IVlrawdtRmQlcQh8McrpqP/97Gz8pEDEYnqA7kqBTqZw0Z5o0WsshGSwiAQ9wNSym4xHejkq
zrKxWP8XCMkcT0NlKlRMoqKKICFKZbqWeSQkQM5y9OEcmB6inNNkJCoM1Ip48+cK3cOE6dqXNVrl
sSTZ8WQKwoB3dJmcYqexR3kAvBYdX6ZxEF+2+6b9h8+tc5G7Y5R2eqycyUossdkCcI3fNVhyc72P
axCjZFWZUgfDGCxg1WNhStrH9L8c59P35JKKug==
```

Comment: Can you add a sample plainText, key and return values?

Comment: @zaitsman I have added my key

Comment: please also add a sample plaintext and output (e.g. what do you get when you say encrypt 'helloworld' with this key?)

Comment: @zaitsman, I am just doing amount=1&currency=AED

Comment: user960567, that is fine. Can you show me what the result base64 looks like when your method in java runs.

Comment: @zaitsman I have added possible encrypted value.

Comment: so this is the following text encrypted, right? `amount=1&currency=AED`

Comment: @zaitsman yes.. BTW these are for sure dumy/test/updated keys just for demo purpose

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since i don't have the private key, i can't decrypt, but at least this produces the right lengthed values.

So try this (you need bouncycastle for reading pem):

```
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Security;

 var keyBytes =
    Convert.FromBase64String(
      "MIIBI...."); // your key here

  AsymmetricKeyParameter asymmetricKeyParameter = PublicKeyFactory.CreateKey(keyBytes);
  RsaKeyParameters rsaKeyParameters = (RsaKeyParameters)asymmetricKeyParameter;
  RSAParameters rsaParameters = new RSAParameters();
  rsaParameters.Modulus = rsaKeyParameters.Modulus.ToByteArrayUnsigned();
  rsaParameters.Exponent = rsaKeyParameters.Exponent.ToByteArrayUnsigned();
  RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
  rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParameters);

  byte[] plaintext = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("amount=1&currency=AED");
  byte[] ciphertext = rsa.Encrypt(plaintext, false);
  string cipherresult = Convert.ToBase64String(ciphertext);
```

Comment: where is AsymmetricKeyParameter and other classes?

Comment: Like i said, you need bouncycastle.

Comment: Genious the problem was finding exponent and modulus.

Comment: @tasos-k Thanks for the namespaces, ReSharper luxury let's me never worry about them

Comment: @zaitsman With VS2015 its also rather easy. Your answer really helped me after maaaany days of searching.